# extract the value from XMLl ike value column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am sharing some two table structure like below.

Table Name: ATTRB

```
CMPG_ID     ATTR_NAME     ATTR_DESC    REQUIRED    TYPE          ATTR_SEQ
12765   Attribute1 attribute1   1            String     2
12765   OFFERTA   Offer       1     Indentification 1
```

Table Name: LEAD

```
CMPG_ID  DYNAMIC_COLUMN
12765             <OFFERTA MaskType="Indentification">20110508</OFFERTA><Attribute1
                MaskType="String">7894568978</Attribute1>
```

I created a procedure like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_Attrs_Get](   
    @CampaignID varchar(10))  
AS  

BEGIN  
SELECT ATTRB.CMPG_ID AS CampaignID,  
  ATTRB.ATTR_NAME AS AttributeName ,  
 ATTRB.ATTR_DESC AS AttributeDesc,  
 ATTRB.REQUIRED AS Required,  
        CASE WHEN ATTRB.REQUIRED = 0 Then 'No'  
        ELSE 'Yes'   
        END as RequiredState,  
 CASE
 WHEN ATTRB.TYPE <> '' THEN 
 ATTRB.TYPE
 ELSE 'String'
 END
 AS AttributeType,  
 ATTRB.ATTR_SEQ AS AttributeSeq  
FROM ATTRB 
WHERE ATTRB.CMPG_ID = @CampaignID ORDER BY ATTR_SEQ
END
```

Now i need to extract the the result like below.

```
CMPG_ID ATTR_NAME      ATTR_DESC   REQUIRED   TYPE             ATTR_SEQ  Value
12765   Attribute1     attribute12  1   String          2      20110508
12765   OFFERTA        Offer        1   Indentification 1      7894568978
```

The Value column shoudl the value extract from LEAD.Dynamic column.

thanks

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I have tried inner join with below, but it gives me more row in result as the master table has more record.. 

i dont know how to extract the value from below column

<OFFERTA MaskType="Indentification">20110508</OFFERTA><Attribute1
                MaskType="String">7894568978</Attribute1>

Comment: <OFFERTA MaskType="Indentification">20110508</OFFERTA><Attribute1
                MaskType="String">7894568978</Attribute1>   Please help me to extract the value from above column

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the element names that can be inside the XML (i.e. the list of element names is a finite enumeration) you can use them as the source of a PIVOT (see the SQL Pivot operator):

```
select DYNAMIC_COLUMN.value('./OFFERTA[1]','varchar(max)') AS OFFERTA
    , DYNAMIC_COLUMN.value('./Attribute1[1]','varchar(max)') AS Attribute1
from    LEAD
WHERE   CMPG_ID = 12765
```

Or else you can just UNION the values to avoid using the PIVOT operator:

```
select 'OFFERTA' AS ATTR_NAME, DYNAMIC_COLUMN.value('./OFFERTA[1]','varchar(max)') AS VALUE
from    LEAD
WHERE   CMPG_ID = 12765
UNION ALL
select 'Attribute1' AS ATTR_NAME, DYNAMIC_COLUMN.value('./Attribute1[1]','varchar(max)') AS VALUE
from    LEAD
WHERE   CMPG_ID = 12765
```

On the other hand, if you don't know all the possible element names (i.e. new element names could be introduced at any time from an outside source), then it's a lot more complicated, since you need to use a sort of "reflection" on the XML.  See the below links:

http://www.jasonfollas.com/wiki/(X(1)S(te4lutlbagfz1qblpl3clbhm))/Default.aspx?Page=SQLXML_Tricks_ElementNames&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_debetta/archive/2010/02/09/shredding-xml-into-hierarchyid-a-new-look.aspx

Comment: Yes that is correct the column will change anytime by outside source.

Comment: Check out the 2nd link above (from Peter DeBetta).  I tried it with your xml and his code worked perfectly.  The only change you need to make is to add a root node in your xml document like so:  declare @x xml = '<root><OFFERTA MaskType="Indentification">20110508</OFFERTA><Attribute1 MaskType="String">7894568978</Attribute1></root>'